# How to become emperor?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

In Dragon Age Inquisition, in the assassination of the emperor, i can choose between some different endings that are rarely known.

This is a screenshot of avoid the hard fight against Florianne: 
[image]

Question:

How to become emperor?

Comment: Do you mean emperor? Take the place of Celene and rule Orlais?

Comment: Yes! I saved before and played about 4 different endings.

Answer (score 1):

The Inquisitor cannot become emperor of Orlais. No matter what you do, [it is not a possible option](http://forum.bioware.com/topic/535049-why-no-option-for-the-inquisitor-as-emperor-of-orlais/).

These are the only options as to who will rule Orlais:

- Celene rules alone
- Celene rules with Briala
- Gaspard rules alone
- Gaspard rules with Briala
- Public truce between Celene, Gaspard and Briala